# Can Sqoop on Azure HDInsight write parquet files?

Tags: azure, sqoop, azure-hdinsight

Does anyone know if Sqoop on Azure HDInsight can write parquet files?
I am using HDInsight with Blob storage and Data Lake storage.
When I run

`sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:sqlserver://<servername>.database.secure.windows.net:1433;database=<dbname>' --username <user> --password "<password>" --table '<tablename>' --target-dir 'wasbs://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<tablename>' --as-parquetfile -m 8  >> sqoop.<table>.out 2>&1`
 
I get error

`17/05/31 16:31:14 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Wrong FS: wasbs://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<tablename>, expected: wasb://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/`

If I change 'wasbs://' to 'wasb://' I get this error:

`17/05/31 16:32:35 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI pattern: dataset:wasb://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<tablename>
Check that JARs for wasb datasets are on the classpath
org.kitesdk.data.DatasetNotFoundException: Unknown dataset URI pattern: dataset:wasb://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/<tablename>
Check that JARs for wasb datasets are on the classpath
        at org.kitesdk.data.spi.Registration.lookupDatasetUri(Registration.java:128)
        at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.exists(Datasets.java:624)
        at org.kitesdk.data.Datasets.exists(Datasets.java:646)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ParquetJob.configureImportJob(ParquetJob.java:106)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.DataDrivenImportJob.configureMapper(DataDrivenImportJob.java:130)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:264)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SQLServerManager.importTable(SQLServerManager.java:163)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:507)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:615)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)`

If I change --target-dir to use data lake `adl://<datalakestorename>.azuredatalakestore.net/<tablename>` with --as-parquetfile
I get error

`7/05/31 17:04:33 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: Wrong FS: adl://<datalakestorename>.azuredatalakestore.net/<tablename>, expected: wasb://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/`

what is the cause for these errors? 
I am puzzled with same

`expected wasb://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/`

for Blob Storage and data lake error.

Path `wasb://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/` happens to be the root and default storage of cluster. Why does it come up as default in error message even though --target-dir is listed? Is it cached somewhere?

Why can't sqoop on HDInsight import data as parquet files?

Comment: This seem may be tied to fs.default.name setting in Hadoop.... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-373

Comment: Looks like core-site.xml config on hadoop cluster fs.defaultFS property is not configured correctly by Microsoft and one have to reconfigure cluster manually. And even after that, one need JAR files for blob storage and/or data lake storage as sqoop uses org.kitesdk to write parquet files and it has to be able to parse wasbs:// and adl:// uri to write parquet to blob and data lake storage...

Comment: Are you still having this error? If no, how did you solve it?

Comment: Yes still do. I am using sqoop to extract as csv.bz2 and then pyspark to convert csv.bz2 to parquet

Comment: Yeah, for me it's no good :) I am using Kite via NiFi and I'm hitting exactly the same error